# Accessing home directory hangs

Tags: 11.10

Occasionally my laptop will hang when trying to access my home directory.  The only fix so far is to reboot and then it goes away for a week.

/var/log/kern.log has the following error:

```
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428107] INFO: task ls:10104 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428114] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428120] ls              D f5dbf6a0     0 10104   9964 0x00000004
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428130]  f3edbd40 00000086 00000001 f5dbf6a0 00000000 00000001 c175dfe0 c1868ec0
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428145]  c1868ec0 054eadaf 0000d250 f5005ec0 ee940cc0 f3e5b300 f3edbcf8 c10e8bfa
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428159]  f3edbd10 f3edbd10 f3edbd10 c102b505 fffba7e8 089fa000 f3edbd38 c10fb528
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428173] Call Trace:
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428189]  [<c10e8bfa>] ? lru_cache_add_lru+0x2a/0x50
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428199]  [<c102b505>] ? __kunmap_atomic+0x75/0xa0
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428207]  [<c10fb528>] ? do_anonymous_page+0x1f8/0x280
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428218]  [<c152b656>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0xc6/0x120
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428225]  [<c152b304>] mutex_lock+0x24/0x40
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428246]  [<f83ab87c>] cifs_reconnect_tcon+0x13c/0x2a0 [cifs]
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428255]  [<c152fa00>] ? vmalloc_fault+0xee/0xee
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428262]  [<c152fc2f>] ? do_page_fault+0x22f/0x4a0
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428276]  [<f83abe3c>] smb_init+0x2c/0x90 [cifs]
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428285]  [<c11aa42e>] ? ext4_htree_store_dirent+0x2e/0x120
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428301]  [<f83b0941>] CIFSSMBQPathInfo+0x41/0x210 [cifs]
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428319]  [<f83c39e4>] ? cifs_get_inode_info+0x224/0x390 [cifs]
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428336]  [<f83c3a21>] cifs_get_inode_info+0x261/0x390 [cifs]
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428354]  [<f83bb35d>] ? build_path_from_dentry+0xcd/0x250 [cifs]
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428362]  [<c102b69e>] ? kmap_atomic_prot+0xde/0x100
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428370]  [<c152c4cd>] ? _raw_spin_lock+0xd/0x10
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428388]  [<f83c6378>] ? _GetXid+0x58/0x80 [cifs]
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428405]  [<f83c4f81>] cifs_revalidate_dentry_attr+0x111/0x1a0 [cifs]
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428423]  [<f83c50e2>] cifs_getattr+0x52/0x120 [cifs]
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428431]  [<c112c5b2>] vfs_getattr+0x42/0x70
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428448]  [<f83c5090>] ? cifs_revalidate_dentry+0x40/0x40 [cifs]
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428455]  [<c112c647>] vfs_fstatat+0x67/0x80
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428461]  [<c112c680>] vfs_lstat+0x20/0x30
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428468]  [<c112c946>] sys_lstat64+0x16/0x30
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428475]  [<c11341ed>] ? link_path_walk+0x79d/0x8a0    
Nov 21 13:54:39 Laptop1 kernel: [231480.428483]  [<c152c8e4>] syscall_call+0x7/0xb
```

Comment: I see some mentions of cifs in there. Is your homedir a network mount? After it fails, can your machine still reach the network server you're mounted from? Anything in the samba logs?

Comment: You should move your Update Manager question to a new question to keep things organised - this site works best when one question actually contains one question :)

Comment: @Caesium, Thank You.  I forgot that I mounted a Windows share in a directory in my home directory.  I'm not yet sure what is wrong with my share/mount, but when I forced it to unmount, everything in the home directory went back to normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to move the answer from a comment into a proper answer - there was a Windows share mounted inside the homedir (see cifs references in the backtrace in the question).

Unmounting this share bypassed the problem but the core of the problem is not yet solved.